# Correct use of django's models.Manager for related objects

Tags: django

I need a custom Manager for Amodel containing a ForeignKey.

```
class AvailableManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def sample(self):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM anapp_amodel """)
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            p = self.model(id=row[0])
            result_list.append(p)
        return result_list


class Amodel(models.Model):
    related_model = models.ForeignKey('AnotherModel', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    available = AvailableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Amodel related to '+unicode(self.related_model)
```

This implementation raises an RelatedObjectDoesNotExist exception when using the manager:

```
>>> Amodel.available.sample()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 459, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File ".../anapp/models.py", line 32, in __unicode__
    return u'Amodel at '+unicode(self.related_model)
  File ".../.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 578, in __get__
    "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Amodel has no related_model.
```

What is the correct way of executing raw sql regarding related fields ? The goal is to achieve a complex SQL query and annotate the results.

**UPDATE:** It's normal that the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist exception is raised because of the line `p = self.model(id=row[0])`. Would it be clever to replace it by a `self.model.objects.get(id=row[0])` to get an instance, thus allowing the resolution of related fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

- `self.model(id=row[0])` that instantiates a Model with the id only
- or `self.model.objects.get(id=row[0])` that performs SELECT request for each instance

I'd rather instantiate the Model with the whole row so that I can proceed to annotate each instance:

```
from django.db import connection


class AvailableManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def sample(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(""" SELECT *, 'annotation' FROM ... """)
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            annotation = row[-1]
            p = self.model(*row[:-1])
            p.annotation = annotation
            result_list.append(p)
        return result_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sample` method instantiates the models with the primary key only, and none of the rest of the row data:

```
p = self.model(id=row[0])
```

so the instance gets no value for the `related_model_id` field.

At the very least you should do:

```
p = self.model(*row)
```

but why are you doing this? It's fine to create separate manager methods, but replacing ORM code with direct database queries - and then returning a *list*, rather than a queryset - is a bad idea and bound to lead to unexpected problems.

**Edit**

This isn't really how you use manager methods. Django already provides a method to run an SQL query and return model instances: [`raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries). So your method just becomes:

```
def sample(self):
    return self.raw(""" SELECT * FROM anapp_amodel """)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, just figured this out. The sample code (in particular the """SELECT * FROM ...""" part ) is for illustration purposes. My use case involves a heavy SQL query here and some annotations. Isn't that the purpose of custom model managers ?

Comment: the list "idea" comes from here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods